# Setup AWS infrastructure to let customers drop files

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture

// Perhaps this is too broad of a question but I've never done any AWS before and am a bit in the weeds - Will delete question if community deems bad.

Using AWS, I want to setup an endpoint where customers can upload files via a POST or PUT with an token for authorization. Alternatively, they could also use SFTP (write only) with a token or user id / password.

So I need:

1. A way for customers to get a secure authorization token somehow. Is there a Vault type product in AWS where only some IPs can request short lived tokens to then use as authN/Z when trying to upload files.
2. I assume that the uploaded files can be in stored in S3, and my process with different permissions can access the uploaded files and do what I need to with them. Parse data into a DB (I can probably figure this out with S3 as well)
3. Optionally, a hosted web page, where once authN/Z as in #1, there's a simple drop zone where they can use the web to upload. (essentially, the site's logic would create the request for them in #1)

I'd be interested in how someone who knows would architect this.

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas:

- [AWS Transfer](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-transfer-family/) provides a managed sFtp front end to S3, user management [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/create-user.html). Beware it's about US$216 per month to enable the service and $0.04 per GB, plus I think you have to pay for AWS Directory Service. It would be cheaper to run a standard sFtp server on Lightsail.
- IAM users with S3 rights is an option, may be more work but it's a LOT cheaper. IAM users cost nothing, and you can set up an S3 bucket so each user has their own folder. It's more work for the user though.
- Write a web-app
- Use Dropbox